# Custom header design for sphinx generated document

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr, sphinx

I am trying to make a custom header design working in our generated sphinx documentation.
The black triangle has to touch the line.

The result should look like this:
[image]

My best result in LaTeX looks like this:

[image]

```
% Header and Footer
\makeatletter
  \fancypagestyle{normal}{
    \fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
    \setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\MyHeaderFamily\thepage}}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{{\MyHeaderFamily\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
    \fancyfoot[RE]{{\MyHeaderFamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{{
        \vspace{0pt}\scalebox{0.2}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}\fill[black, ultra thick] (1,1) -- (2,1) -- (1.5,0) -- cycle;
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        \vspace{0pt}\vbox to 0pt{\makebox[\headwidth]{\hrulefill}\vss}
        \\
        \vspace{0pt}\MyHeaderFamily SAFETY, \py@release}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  }
\makeatother
```

I tried various positive and negative values for \vspace but it did not work.
Has anyone a better trick for me?

Thanks in advance,

Gunther

Update @Bernard:

```
% Header and Footer
\newcommand{\shiftleft}[2]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[#1][l]{#2}}}
\newcommand{\shiftright}[2]{\makebox[#1][r]{\makebox[0pt][l]{#2}}}
\makeatletter
  \fancypagestyle{normal}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\MyHeaderFamily\thepage}}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{{\MyHeaderFamily\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
    \fancyfoot[RE]{{\MyHeaderFamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{{\MyHeaderFamily SAFETY}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{{\shiftright{8pt}{\raisebox{-4pt}{\LARGE $\blacktriangledown$}}}}
    \fancyhead[RE]{{\shiftleft{15pt}{\raisebox{-4pt}{\LARGE $\blacktriangledown$}}}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  }
\makeatother
```

This is rendered like this:
[image]

I like it more than the original design!

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Wouldn't it it be easier to use `$\blacktriangledown`$ rather than using a hammersledge like TiKZ to draw such a simple figure? You can fine-tune its vertical position with `\raisebox`.

Comment: @Bernard This looks promising!
`\fancyhead[LO]{{\shiftright{8pt}{\raisebox{-4pt}{\LARGE $\blacktriangledown$}}}}`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's better to use the `ex` unit for \raisebox – if you change the document font size, it should automatically adapt to the new font size.

Comment: Often, the simplest solution is to put in one of the header fields a `\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-x,-y){Some text}.....\end{picture}` with a properly defined `\unitlength`. See the `fancyhdr` documentation for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of Pieter and Bernard I could reproduce the original design.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\MyHeaderFamily{\sffamily\Large}
\newcommand{\shiftleft}[2]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[#1][l]{#2}}}
\newcommand{\shiftright}[2]{\makebox[#1][r]{\makebox[0pt][l]{#2}}}
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{normal}{
    \fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
    \setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\MyHeaderFamily\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{\MyHeaderFamily\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot[RE]{\MyHeaderFamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\shiftleft{20pt}{\raisebox{-1ex}{\LARGE $\blacktriangledown$}}%
        \setlength{\unitlength}{\baselineskip}%
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(0,-1.2){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\MyHeaderFamily SAFETY, Release 1.0}}
    \end{picture}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{%
        \setlength{\unitlength}{\baselineskip}%
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(0,-1.2){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\MyHeaderFamily SAFETY, Release 1.0}}
        \end{picture}%
        \shiftright{8pt}{\raisebox{-1ex}{\LARGE $\blacktriangledown$}}}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{normal}
\begin{document}
    \section{Intro}
    
    \lipsum
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you all! Your help was invaluable!

Best Regards,
Gunther

Answer (score 2):

As in my remark, this solution uses `picture` to position the text.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\MyHeaderFamily{\sffamily\Large}
\makeatletter
  \fancypagestyle{normal}{
    \fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
    \setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\MyHeaderFamily\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{\MyHeaderFamily\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot[RE]{\MyHeaderFamily\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
    \fancyhead[RO]{{\LARGE $\blacktriangledown$}%
        \setlength{\unitlength}{\baselineskip}%
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
          \put(0,-1.2){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\MyHeaderFamily SAFETY, Release 1.0}}
        \end{picture}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{%
        \setlength{\unitlength}{\baselineskip}%
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
          \put(0,-1.2){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\MyHeaderFamily SAFETY, Release 1.0}}
        \end{picture}%
      {\LARGE $\blacktriangledown$}}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  }
\makeatother
\pagestyle{normal}
\begin{document}
\section{Intro}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]